# Mysql query to select quiz options as A B C D with using extra foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on quiz concept so first all 20 question will be fetched, then each question will be loop and with every loop I am passing question id and getting options of those related question, but my requirement is to get option like A B C D infront of all options without using extra loop

Table structure for options:

```
id    option_value       question_id

1      some value          1
2      some value          1
3      some value          1
4      some value          1
5      some value          2
6      some value          2
7      some value          2
8      some value          2
```

Expected output:

```
option_id   option_name option_value
 1           A           some value
 2           B           some value
 3           C           some value
 4           D           some value
 5           A           some value
 6           B           some value
 7           C           some value
 8           D           some value



$question_list // all 20 question using select *



foreach($question_list as $list){
$this->db->select('id,option_vaue')->from('option')->where('question_id',$list->id)->order_by('id','asc')->get()->result();
}
```

Comment: what do you means by `is to get option like A B C D infront of all options without using extra loop`??

Comment: please show us in picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MySQL window function if you're using version 8.0.0 or above. The equivalent MySQL query would look like this -

```
SELECT 
`id`,
`option_value`,
`question_id`,
CHAR(64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `question_id` ORDER BY `id` ASC)) 'Option'
FROM `question`
```

Comment: Aakash Johari I tried your code but showing error wrog query,please check .....